# How to parse div in this html code?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have following html html code: 
[image]

The texts that I want to parse is shown with red arrow. This is how I tried to parse `h2`:

```
Elements elements = document.select("div#app div#timetable-content-holder h2");
```

But unfortunately `elements`'s size is zero.

But I checked that `document.select(div#app).size()` is 1, but `document.select(div#app div#timetable-content-holder).size()` is 0. If it is zero , it means that I could not do `for` loop over elements and never could achieve others text shown on image,because they are inside this `div`. I suppose that problem is that `timetable-content-holder` has some `data-reactroot`. I don't know why it is there. 
I refer to the page through the URL. 
How to solve this problem? Why `elements`'s size becomes always zero?

HTML code for those who need(the text that needs to be parsed marked)

```
    <div id="app">

<div data-reactroot="" id="timetable-content-holder">

<div> </div> 

<div> </div> 

<div> </div> 

<div> </div> 

//a lot of div above(closed) 

<h2>I need it1</h2> ( how to get this) 



<div class="timetable-holder gr-holder">

<div class="timetable-day gr">

<div class="timetable-day-title">I need it2</div>

<div class="timetable-card" data-day="1" data-time="1">

<div class="timetable-time">

08:00<!-- /react-text --> // I need it3

<!-- react-text: 57 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 58 -->

08:50<!-- /react-text --></div><span class="font-icon down-arrow"></span><div class="timetable-subject" title="title">I need it4</div>

//below is also closing divs
```

Comment: Can please add a html rather than screen shot?

Comment: @soorapadman Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can write the following code to get the result.
First create the element of id `timetable-content-holder` and use `get(0)`(other wise it will return list of elements) so that document will return only first element of id. then u can directly select `h2` from that element and u will get your **first answer**.
`ele1` : Is your first text you want to parse and so on

```
Element ele1 = document.select("div[id=timetable-content-holder]").get(0);
ele1 = ele1.select("h2").get(0);
Element ele2 = document.select("div[class=timetable-day-title]").get(0);
Element ele3 = document.select("div[class=timetable-time]").get(0);
Element ele4 = document.select("div[title=Subject]").get(0);
```

The result of above code is :

```
IT NEED TO BE PARSED
THIS IS ALSO
"08:00"
Subject
```

Comment: You mean that it is possible to refer to child not reffering to its parent? For example you referred to `timetable-day-title` not refferring to `app` and `timetable-cotent-holder` and other two divs

Comment: I checked following : `document.select("div.timetable-day-title").size()` is zero. Why?

Comment: yes we can directly refer to child without referring to the parent. as in `select` we need to pass the CSS path.

Comment: I checked in my local system there is no issue with `document.select("div.timetable-day-title").size()` the size is `1`

Comment: Yes,it works only if html writter as a string locally. I also checked that. But If I connect through the URL, your method does not work. Why? How can I send you URL?

Comment: Okays then share the link in the comment or u can add link in your question itself.

Comment: [link](http://schedule.iitu.kz/#/g/timetable/group/13812) I need there subject's names,time etc. I tried your suggestion,but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to by printing the doc of given URL by                                            `String doc = Jsoup.connect(#yourURL).get().toString();
System.out.println(doc);` and we found some HTML is missing while parsing the document. then i tried opening the page source of given URL by right click on google chrome. then we can see only `<div id="app"></div>(Same as jsoup)`. So what i suspecting is that that data coming inside `div id="app"` is coming through javascript and JSoup does not support java script.

Comment: can u use selenium for getting the page source ?

Comment: this might be the reason u are getting `document.select(div#app).size()` is 1, but `document.select(div#app div#timetable-content-holder).size()` is 0.

Comment: But you have choosen 'Show code of page' , you needed to choose 'Show code of element'. Then html code of inside div#app will be shown. So,can you try. But anyways,it didn't help me. What can I do? What is selenium?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154038/discussion-between-abhay-gupta-and-andy11).